# How can I run a script every time a certain GNU screen changes?

Tags: shell-script, gnu-screen

I am running a Minecraft server in a GNU screen that is usually detached. What I want to do is to watch the screen and run a script every time something is printed to the screen (which the server program does quite frequently).

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a wrapper script:

```
#!/bin/sh
while IFS= read -r line
do
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
    # add your command/script here to be run on every new line printed
done < /dev/stdin
```

You can use the above script by piping the output from your program to the script

For example if above script is called `./wrapper.sh` and your program is `prog`:

```
prog | ./wrapper.sh
```

Note that if something is printed in standard error by `prog`, it won't processed by the script unless you redirect it or handle stderr separately.

Comment: What if the command to start the server is only `java -Xmx1024M -jar craftbukkit.jar -o true`, can the last line of the wrapper script be `done < java -Xmx1024M -jar craftbukkit.jar -o true`?

Comment: I suppose you could add your `java ...` command piping to `while`, eg. `java ... | while read line ...`